# How do I toggle the enabled status of a radio button group in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons with a class of "laser2" on each button.  I have a checkbox with an ID of "duaL-laser".  I am trying to toggle the availability of the radio button group with the checkbox.  I know the class toggling works (for display purposes).  Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    //$('.laser2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#dual-laser').click(function() {
        $('div#power-listing2').toggleClass('disable');
        $('.laser2').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    if ($('#dual-laser').attr('checked', false)) {
        $('.laser2').attr('disabled', true);
    }

});
</script>
```

This works when I check the checkbox.  But when I uncheck the checkbox, the radio buttons remain enabled.  Even though the if statement is true at the bottom of the code.  What gives?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle for this?

Comment: That fiddle appears to be missing some HTML.

Comment: No worries.  Once you create the new fiddle you need to click update and copy/paste the new URL over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
if ($('#dual-laser').attr('checked', false)) {
        $('.laser2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

to this:

```
if ($('#dual-laser').prop('checked')) {
        $('.laser2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

Right now you are setting that attribute and I suspect you want to get it.

**UPDATE**

Also, should the above statement be inside of your click event?  Right now it's only being executed on document ready.  Something like this:

```
$('#dual-laser').click(function() {
        $('div#power-listing2').toggleClass('disable');
        //$('.laser2').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.laser2').attr('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a simplified fiddle that should do what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/pHJ5u/3/

Comment: Nope.  They're still enabled after I uncheck the box.

Comment: Your updated code works fine.  I was on the wrong track.  Thanks, Abe!